# Python exporting custom user input to file

Tags: python, input

First things first: I am using a Raspberry pi (Raspbian) with python 2.7.5 from the terminal (with nano).

I've been surfing the web for a couple of days now, trying to find the answer to my question.

I have a barcode scanner attached to my 'pi' and I'm trying to export the print command plus my barcode and additional information a user has to type in after scanning the barcode, here's where im stuck now. I've tried running the file like this:

```
sudo python inputdevice.py >> output.txt
```

But the problem is that it doesn't show anything in the terminal. It does output to output.txt. But I want it show up in my terminal so other people can easily use it. It should print: 'scanner is connected!' and then 'Please scan barcode now'. This also means that when I add another line which prints: 'Please provide extra information' and then opens a newline to let the user type in things like the date and adress of destination. They can't see it.

Just to clear up: Once you launch: 'sudo python inputdevice.py > output.txt.
You see just open space where you can type in and press enter after and it WILL export 'Please scan barcode' -> [barcode] etc. in the "output.txt" file. I hope someone will be able to answer my question. (I'm seriously not even sure if this is possible.

Thanks anyway,
- Max

```
from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes, list_devices, categorize
from select import select
import signal, sys
import os.path
import sys
import subprocess

keys = {
    # Scancode: ASCIICode
    0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'1', 3: u'2', 4: u'3', 5: u'4', 6: u'5', 7: u'6', 8: u'7', 9: u'8',
    10: u'9', 11: u'0', 12: u'-', 13: u'=', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'Q', 17: u'W', 18: u'E', 19: u'R',
    20: u'T', 21: u'Y', 22: u'U', 23: u'I', 24: u'O', 25: u'P', 26: u'[', 27: u']', 28: u' ', 29: u' ',
    30: u'A', 31: u'S', 32: u'D', 33: u'F', 34: u'G', 35: u'H', 36: u' ', 37: u'K', 38: u'L', 39: u';',
    40: u'"', 41: u'`', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'\\', 44: u'Z', 45: u'X', 46: u'C', 47: u'V', 48: u'B', 49: u'N',
    50: u'M', 51: u',', 52: u'.', 53: u'/', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT', 100: u'RALT'
}


if not os.path.exists('/dev/input/by-id/usb-040b_6543-if01-event-kbd'):  #this is the scanners ID
        print "Scanner isn't connected ;("
        exit()    #if scaner not connected then exit
else:
        print "Scanner is connected! :)"
        print "Please scan barcode now"

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print '   Stopping Module'
    dev.ungrab()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/by-id/usb-040b_6543-if01-event-kbd")

dev.grab()

barcode = ""
for event in dev.read_loop():
    if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
        data = categorize(event)
        if data.keystate == 1 and data.scancode != 42: # Catch only keydown, and not Enter
            if data.scancode == 28:
                if barcode.startswith("   "):
                        print "Your input is:"
                        print barcode[3:]
                else:
                        print "Your input is:"
                        print barcode
                barcode = ""
        else:
                barcode += keys[data.scancode]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use some kind of logger. Python has something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html. This module should solve your problem with logging. And I think that it is the best idea.

.. or you can just use

```
python script.py | tee output.txt
```

which should solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a shot!